# Django - Boolean field with Single True

Tags: python, django, django-models, database

I want a boolean field that only allows for ONE of them to be *True* based on a foreign key (*User*). I am now sure how to word this or really search for it, but I was able to get a simple implementation working, but I do not like it. It feels clunky and wrong. Anyways, the best way to get what I mean is you see it, here you go:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    _is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __get_is_main(self):
        return self._is_main

    def __set_is_main(self, is_main):
        if (is_main):
            active_keys = API_Key.objects.filter(_is_main=True, owner=self.owner)
            if (len(active_keys) == 1 and self in active_keys):
                return
            else:
                for key in active_keys:
                    if (key.is_main):
                        key.is_main = False
                        key.save()
        self._is_main = is_main
        self.save()

    is_main = property(__get_is_main, __set_is_main)
```

I only want is_main to be *True* for each *owner* ONCE, no more then once. These are for API keys. So the owner can have many API Keys but only one is set to the main one. This is the only way I could figure out how to implement this. Anyone have a better way to do this? I am using MySQL if it matters.

Comment: BTW if your filter query incldes  `_is_main=True` why you checks in if `if (key.is_main):` ?

Comment: haha! Good catch. I kind of missed that. Fixed

Comment: With fiter query you can add `API_Key.objects.filter(_is_main=True, owner=self.owner).exclude(pk=self.pk)` to exclude `self` and simplify if condition as `if active_keys:`

Comment: I mean this @[codepade](http://codepad.org/6CIcS3Da)

Comment: Oh cool. That helps a lot too. Still rather new to Django. I really like Python so i am trying to use it instead of Yii Framework in PHP (I REALLY hate PHP)

EDIT: Updated to reflect your changes. The if statement would not be needed, it should return an empty list if none exist and simply never run the foreach loop

Comment: I even quite new to Django like 7 days. So I didn't posted answer ;) So check again if I am correct.

Comment: Yes you are correct in your edit part

Comment: You are doing good still xD I just really want a way that does not automatically forces me to save it all. Preferably if I change is_main to True, it does not bounds checking on the others, but then when I run .save(), it automatically sets all the other ones to False.

EDIT: Now that I said that, I could override the .save() fucntion

Comment: I don't now if there us some `.update()`  avilable in Django ..

Comment: Try: `active_keys = API_Key.objects.filter(_is_main=True, owner=self.owner).exclude(pk=self.pk).update(is_main=True)`  Reff: [Updating multiple objects at once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

Comment: You should  **not** change in question on the bases of comments!  Even if you change update question as **EDIT**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need that field but have a singleton pointing to a main key. Something along these lines:

```
class Key(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    @property
    def is_main(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'is_main')

    def set_main(self):
        # update MainKey instance here


class MainKey(models.Model):
    key = models.ForeignKey(Key, related_name='is_main')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = 1
        super(MainKey, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but I think this just makes my code much more messy. I implemented the changes Grijesh mentioned in the comments on the questions and they made a difference.

It would make me need to call a third table for the keys (already need key, user and this would also add mainkey).

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a custom field to achieve this:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-exclusivebooleanfield

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    _is_main = ExclusiveBooleanField(default=False, on=('owner',))
```

It works by wrapping the model's save method.

Comment: Curious to know if it still works 8 years later :)

Comment: @DavidDahan the concept will do, but I only maintained and tested that library up to Django 1.8 - consider it unmaintained now. It might still work but it's likely there have been breaking changes in Django 2, 3 and 4