# What is the best way to indicate Main/Preffered object of ones related by they ForeignKey in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I got these models:

```
Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=10)

Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_lenght=10)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

I want to indicate which of phone numbers if proffered for each person
For now I got:

```
Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=10)
    main_phone = models.OneToOneField(Phone)

Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_lenght=10)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

And then filtering choices in form and validating them to make sure the Person is owner of main_phone

<strike>It should work</strike> buts looks little "spaghetti like". So maybe you have some best practices to share?

Comment: It dont work because models validate from top to bottom so if `Person` id on top it fails becouse there is no such model as `Phone` yet and other vay around with `ForeignKeyPerson

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    is_main = model.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_main:
            Phone.objects.filter(person=self.person).update(is_main=False)
        super(Phone, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You should be using the `@transaction.atomic` (Django >= 1.6) or `@transaction.commit_on_success` (Django < 1.6) decorator to wrap the update and save in a transaction, and prevent the update from occurring should the save fail. That will ensure no data is lost should an error ever occur.

Comment: I seen this approach here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924046/django-boolean-field-with-single-true but it seem over complicated...

Comment: @knbk can you point me to some tutorial/ documentation about this decorator?

Comment: Sure, here is the [new documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) and [pre-1.6 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/).

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a custom field which encapsulates the overridden-save-method pattern (as also used in @Eugene's answer).

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-exclusivebooleanfield

```
Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    is_main = ExclusiveBooleanField(default=False, on=('person',))
```

Comment: this is great but I cant get it to work with `CreateWithInlinesView` from django-extra-views - https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views. It throws `reduce() arg 2 must support iteration` Any idea how to make it work with inlines?

Comment: @Lord_JABA I just noticed I missed the trailing comma in my tuple for `on` in code above (corrected now)... could you post code of your model where you use the field?